# bash - Comparing variables

Tags: bash

I am trying to do the following in bash:

get my external IP

read first line of a file

compare both values

if it is not the same, delete the file and recreate it with the current address

I really don't know why this fails, all my script does is to output my current address and the first line of the file (which by the way is simply "asd" for testing)

```
#!/bin/bash          

IP= curl http://ipecho.net/plain
OLD= head -n 1 /Users/emse/Downloads/IP/IP.txt
if [ "$IP" = "$OLD" ]; then
  exit
else
  rm /Users/emse/Downloads/IP/IP.txt
  $IP> /Users/emse/Downloads/IP/IP.txt
  exit
fi
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some obvious problems in your script:

1. Don't put spaces on either side of equal sign if you want to do assignment
2. You want the output of `curl`, `head` so wrap them in backticks (`)
3. You want to write `$IP` into the file, not to execute the content of it as a command, so `echo` it

The script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash          

IP=`curl http://ipecho.net/plain`
OLD=`head -n 1 /Users/emse/Downloads/IP/IP.txt`
if [ "$IP" = "$OLD" ]; then
  exit
else
  rm /Users/emse/Downloads/IP/IP.txt
  echo $IP > /Users/emse/Downloads/IP/IP.txt
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer qingbo, just a tad bit of refinement:

```
#!/bin/bash          

IP=`curl http://ipecho.net/plain`
OLD=`head -n 1 /Users/emse/Downloads/IP/IP.txt`
if [ "$IP" != "$OLD" ]; then
    echo $IP > /Users/emse/Downloads/IP/IP.txt  #  > creates/truncates/replaces IP.txt
fi
```

Comment: Yeah that cleans a lot. Also the file name could be made a variable :-)